# Lists with Children in Grommet UI and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, next.js, grommet

I've got the following list in a Grommet UI component:

```
import { List } from "grommet";
import { ResourceLink, ResourceLinkProps } from "./ResourceLink";

type ResourceListProps = {
  resources: ResourceLinkProps[],
}

const ResourceList: React.FC<ResourceListProps> = ({resources}: ResourceListProps) => {
  return (
    <List data={resources} border={false} pad="none">
      {(resource: ResourceLinkProps) => <ResourceLink id={resource.id} name={ resource.name } urlPart={ resource.urlPart } />}
    </List>
  );
};

export default ResourceList;
```

I get an error saying: `Type '(resource: ResourceLinkProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'. Did you mean to call this expression?`

If I wrap the children in a fragment I get an error saying `TypeError: children is not a function`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there some sort of syntax I need to use? How do I go about calling the function @dhaker?

Comment: Please add `ResourceLinkProps` and `resources` data, looks like there is some issue

Comment: An example for your reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/grommet-v2-template-forked-w1will?file=/index.tsx

Comment: yeah, in that example you can see the type hint saying: "Type '(datum: dataType) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'."