# "not assignable to type" error for Grommet List with Children in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, grommet

I am using grommet component library for my react app and I tried using List component for one of my requirement. I referred grommet documentation :
[Example](https://storybook.grommet.io/?path=/story/visualizations-list-children--children&globals=theme:base)

and accordingly tried using the List component with children using typescript. Below is my code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Box, List, Tip, Text } from 'grommet';
    import { Gremlin } from 'grommet-icons';
    
    const dataList: { city: string; state: string }[] = [
      { city: 'Boise', state: 'Idaho' },
      { city: 'Fort Collins', state: 'Colorado' },
      { city: 'Bay Area', state: 'California' },
      { city: 'San Diego', state: 'California' },
    ];
    
    const renderListItem = (datum: { city: string; state: string }) => (
      <Tip content={datum.state} dropProps={{ align: { left: 'right' } }}>
        <Box direction="row-responsive" gap="medium" align="center">
          <Gremlin size="large" />
          <Text weight="bold">{datum.city}</Text>
        </Box>
      </Tip>
    );
    
    const Children: React.FC = () => (
      <Box pad="large" height="100%" align="center">
        <List data={dataList} pad="medium" border={false}>
          {renderListItem}
        </List>
      </Box>
    );
    
    export default Children;
```

But this gives me following error:

> Type '(datum: {    city: string;    state: string;}) =>
> React.JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '(((...args: any[]) =>
> any) & (string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string |
> JSXElementConstructor> | Iterable | ReactPortal |
> null)) | undefined'.   Type '(datum: {    city: string;    state:
> string;}) => React.JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '((...args:
> any[]) => any) & string'.
> Type '(datum: {    city: string;    state: string;}) => React.JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(46, 3): The expected type comes from property 'children'
> which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> ListExtendedProps<{ city: string; state: string; }> & { children?:
> ReactNode; }'
>
> ```
> const renderListItem: (datum: {
>     city: string;
>     state: string;
> }) => React.JSX.Element
> ```

I see similar question on SO : [Lists with Children in Grommet UI and TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73769020/lists-with-children-in-grommet-ui-and-typescript). But I dont see any answers there too. I tried by passing various types but all in vain.
Could any one please throw some light on this ?

**Update:**
Seems like its a issue with grommet and an issue has been raised [here](https://github.com/grommet/grommet/issues/7160).

Thanks